# postgresql partition large dataset and random select 3 from a category

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions

I'm a novice when It comes to database programming or programming in general.
But I hope you can help me.

I've a database with circa 9mln rows and there is a column named category. Some rows belong in the same category there maybe be 10 in the same, while others may only have 1 or 2.

I would like to make a new table where RANDOM three rows are selected from the same category. Basically filtering or excluding the rest.

If there are categories with less then 3 rows then only the available rows will be selected.

I've looked around on the forum and a friend told me I needed to do this with PARTITION. I've tried the following but this doesn't do what I want. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Create table test as
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY random()) as rn
FROM data2016 ) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Just change to `where rn <= 3`

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Many thx it worked.

Comment: Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY random()) as rn
    FROM data2016
  ) sub
WHERE rn <= 3;
```